# Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've just starting to add Redux to my React application. And when starting to set up everything inside of my `index.js` file I recived this error: [image]
I've been searching around and I understand that it has to do with that  the `document` element is not available yet, but I don't understand why because in my `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>My Qlocx</title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.min.css" type="text/css" >
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I've included my `root` at the bottom. Here's my `index.js` file by the way:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.css'

import Layout from './components/Start/Layout'
import LayoutUser from './components/User/LayoutUser'
import LayoutProfile from './components/Profile/LayoutProfile'
import DoorDetails from './components/Start/DoorDetails'
import DoorsSetting from './components/Start/DoorsSetting'

const App = document.getElementById('root')

const routes = {
  '/': Layout,
  '/users': LayoutUser,
  '/profile': LayoutProfile,
  '/log/:itemId': DoorDetails,
  '/settings/:itemId': DoorsSetting
}

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router routes={routes} />,
    App
  </Provider>
)
```

I apologies if my error is super basic, but I'm really new to this React/ Redux world. Thanks for reading!

Comment: I don't understand how you get that error because the only JS file your HTML loads is jQuery.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#render

Answer (score 1):

As it says [in the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#render), the second argument to `ReactDOM.render` is the element to render to (the container). You haven't provided one. You probably wanted the one with `id="root"`:

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router routes={routes} />,
    App
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root") // <====
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router routes={routes} />,
  </Provider>
,App);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made what looks like a simple error, putting your DOM element in the middle of the components to be rendered, whereas it should be the render method's 2nd argument.

```
const App = document.getElementById('root')

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router routes={routes} />
  </Provider>,
  App
)
```

This is made extra confusing because you've given the DOM element a capitalised name. It's clearer in lowercase:

```
const root = document.getElementById('root')

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router routes={routes} />
  </Provider>,
  root
)
```

Comment: Oh shoot! I totally forgot that it would be the last. And I will fix that.